# How to update a nested object with nestjs and mongooose

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I have a nested object called "items", which can have multiple objects on it. Each one has an ID, and through this ID I wanna update only the respective object. This is how my post request looks like:
object.service.ts

```
{
    "object_name": "Example",
    "versions": [{
     "version_name": "Version One",
     "items": [
       { "item_id": "1", "item_name": "Item Name A" },
       {"item_id": "2", "item_name": "Item Name B" }
     ]
   }]
}
```

So for example, I wanna update the item named "Item Name C", so I update it through the id 4.

The IDs will be auto-generated using an UUID lib, what I put here is just an example. The Nestjs project I have architectured has an schema for the main object, with the request properties on it. I did it in a way that versions follows an interface like that:

```
export interface IVersions {
  version_name: string;
  items: IItems[];
}
```

And the items also has an interface:

```
export interface IItems{
    item_id: string;
    item_name: string;
}
```

I am able to update the whole object by passing the update.dto for it using findByIdAndUpdate, but could not succeed when trying to update only one object by its ID. I have digged a bit online and tried the findOneAndUpdate, but still I have to pass the dto for the entire object and it does nothing:

```
` async updateItem(
    item_id: any,
    updateObject: UpdateWObject,
  ): Promise<Object> {
    return this.objectModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { 'versions.items.item_id': item_id },
      { $set: { 'versions.items.$': updateObject.versions } },
      {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
      },
    );
  }
```

Is there a way to update the nested "items", which is inside another object "versions"?